# Is it possible to use an ArrayList to store strings in a method, then call the method in a new file?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to use an array list to store strings and then output them into their own file form a separate file. (So there are 3 files involved. 1 that has the array list and the values, 1 that is creating the new file and calling the list, and 1 that after it is created by the second file will store the strings from the array.)

Here is the code from files 1:

```
public final String CHEESE = "Cream Cheese";
public final String BUT = "Butter";
public final String JELLY = "Peach Jelly";
public final String JAM = "Blueberry Jam";
public final String NUT = "Nutella";

public String getTopping()
{
  ArrayList aList = new ArrayList)(;

  if (creamCheese.isSelected())
     aList.add(CHEESE);
  if (butter.isSelected())
     alist.add(BUT);
  if (peachJelly.isSelected())
     aList.add(JELLY);
  if (blueberryJam.isSelected())
     aList.add(JAM);
  if (nutella.isSelected())
     aList.add(NUT);


  return aList;
}
```

Here is the code from file 2:

```
File file = new File("output.txt");
PrintWriter writer = null;

try
{
   writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file));
}
catch (IOException ex)
{
   System.out.println("Exception");
}

writer.println(bagels.getBagels());


int size = toppings.getTopping.size();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    writer.println(toppings.getTopping.toString())
}

writer.close();
```

Comment: `public String getTopping()` would have to be `public List<String> getTopping()` and `writer.println(toppings.getTopping.toString())` should be `writer.println(toppings.getTopping().get(i))`

Comment: And what you really want is a `Map`.

Comment: What do you mean a map? And I'm getting an error with public List<String> getTopping(). Do I need to pass all the variables to it?

Comment: MadProgrammer, if you would please post what you told me to change in an answer I'll accept it. Thanks for the help, it's working.